# Aiogram filters

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

I have a question about aiogram. I can't figure out how to implement what I need.

I have a database with users who have their own roles (user, administrator, employee) there can be a dozen of such roles. I need a certain handler to be responsible only for a certain role.

I wrote a filter that checks the user's role:

```py
class RoleFilter(BoundFilter):
    key = 'is_role'
    required = False

    def __init__(self, is_role):
        self.is_role = is_role

    async def check(self, msg: types.Message):
        user:User = User.query.filter_by(telegram_id = msg.from_user.id, role =   self.is_role).first()
        return False if user is None else True

dp.filters_factory.bind(RoleFilter)
```

And this is what the handler looks like:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['install'], is_role = "admin") 
async def install_handler(msg: types.Message):
     puss
```

And everything works as I need!

The problem is that, in my version, it will make requests to the database until one of the handlers matches. That is, I have 5 handlers before they are needed and it will check all of them.

How can I fix the request issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use new object RoleFilter("role"). For example:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['install'], RoleFilter("admin")) 
async def install_handler(msg: types.Message):
     puss
```